# Maximizing the sum of the squares of numbers whose sum is constant

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, discrete-optimization, discrete-calculus

I wonder how one goes about to find the maximum of $\sum v_i^2$, the $v_i$'s being positive integers whose sum $\sum_i v_i$ is fixed.

Comment: Well, as these things go, the maximum is achieved either when all the $v_i$ are equal or when all but one of them are zero.

Comment: @martycohen: They can't be zero, they're positive.

Comment: Then, as the answers below show, all but one are 1.

Answer (score 4):

If there are two numbers with $1\lt v_j\le v_k$, you can decrease $v_j$ and increase $v_k$ to increase the sum of squares. Thus at most one of the $v_i$ is greater than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that you're aiming to cover as much of the $\sum_i v_i$ square as possible:

[image]

The bigger the largest inner square, the closer it gets to covering more of the background square. The maximum  sum of squares is reached when all but one of the $v_i$ is at the specified minimum - in this case, $1$.

Comment: Excel sheet with coloured squares, it’s Mondrian.  https://moco-choco.com/2013/11/21/how-to-identify-famous-artists-by-their-paintings/

Comment: I'll take any compliment I can get. I'll even misinterpret criticism as compliments if necessary :-)

Comment: Joffan, maybe I should have included some text. I like the picture. I was going to post an answer with a Mondrian painting, but I thought you might not like that, and I do get some criticism for posting fake answers, found it  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/is-it-allowed-and-encouraged-to-post-non-answer-joke-to-low-quality-questions  The best description of artists at that web page is van Eyck

Comment: I should have said, I really liked the "instant-art-expertise" link. And most days you have to work pretty hard to upset me.